# Is it this way of routing correct in Laravel? applying different routs for same endpoints

Tags: php, laravel

Recently I decided to implement multilingual feature on website so the way I want to use is by endpoints.

for example :

```
/{all available endpoints}

/fa/{all available endpoints}
```

Generally if I want to do this I need to copy all routing into two places and it's not mature.

So I put all of my endpoints by closure to a variable and used them along with my root endpoints.

please see the picture below.

do you think am I right?

[image]

Comment: I have an idea about adding a new feature to Laravel, for defining multiple roots for same controller : Route::get(['/','fa'],'controller@index);

Comment: https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/ or https://laravel-news.com/register-multilingual-routes-in-laravel might be a good starting point.